# Защищенный вход на страницу

Tags: php, аутентификация

Есть админка. Как лучше реализовать механизм защиты от "любопытных".
Сейчас сделано так: 
Страница входа: если пароль совпадает, то в куки записывается ключ.
При заходе на  страницы админки идет проверка, если ключ совпадает, то заходит; нет - идет переадресация на страницу входа.

Comment: а может в сессию добавите ключ после успешной авторизации и будете этот ключ менять при каждом переходе ссылок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непонятно, с чем сравнивается записанный в куки ключ.

Обычно этим занимается встроенный в РНР механизм [сессий](http://phpfaq.ru/sessions): после проверки пароля в сессию пишется id пользователя, и на каждой странице проверяются его права доступа. В самом простом случае просто наличие id.

Вот пример авторизации с использованием PDO и правильного механихма хэширования паролей:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->execute($_POST['username']);
    $user = $stmt->fetch();
    if($user && password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id'];
    }
}
```

после этого проверяем

```
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['userid']) {
     header("Location: /auth.php")
     exit;
}
```